# Facebook App is loading slow

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk, performance

My Facebook app is loading slow.
When I get rid of the SDK PHP it becomes much faster.

Am I doing it on the wrong way? Is there a faster way?

```
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/facebook/src/facebook.php';
$appId = 'appid';
$appSecret = 'appsecret';

// Create your Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
$facebook = new Facebook( 
    array(
      'appId'  => $appId,
      'secret' => $appSecret,
      'fileUpload' => true,
      'cookie' => true
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();
```